# How do I use a web font library like fontsource in TailWindCSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to import and use a font from the @fontsource repository with tallwindCSS and React
I've installed the font with `npm install @fontsource/advent-pro`
I've added the font to index.js: `@import "@fontsource/advent-pro"`
and I've added them to the tallwind.config.js:

```
  module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        "logoText": ['advent-pro', sans]
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I'm then expecting to be able to add a class with className="font-logoText", but that doesn't seem to give me the font I'm expecting. What've I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I was having the same issue.

What I found worked was changing the font name in the declaration in the tailwind config file to use the font name rather than the package name. In your case this would be:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        "logoText": ['Advent Pro', sans]
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Then after importing the fontsource package into the `index.ts` file (or wherever you want to use it) using the classname `className="font-logoText"` as you were doing should work. Hope you managed to fix it but thought I would drop my solution on here in case anyone else was looking for it.